# Change Icon in Bootgrid

Tags: javascript, plugins, jquery-plugins, jquery-bootgrid

how do I change the sorting icons in [Bootgrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/). I've tried the following as per the documentation but not working;

```
$("#grid-basic").bootgrid({
    icon: 'fa',
    iconColumns: 'fa-bars',
    ...
});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not documented very well but you need to set css classes like this:

```
$("#grid-basic").bootgrid({
    css: {
        icon: 'fa',
        iconColumns: 'fa-bars'
    },
    ...
});
```